# Get Marketing list ID by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get the id of a marketing list created in Microsoft Dynamics based on the list's name. I will then use the id to add crm contacts to the list (this I can do fine using the id of the list)

I can't find any instructions in the documentation that explains how to do this. I have tried the following code but i get the error that no entity by that name exists:

```
    var request = new RetrieveRequest();
    request.Target = new EntityReference("new list 1", listId);
    RetrieveResponse response = _organizationService.Execute(request) as RetrieveResponse;
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is make it possible for an administrator of the crm to identify the marketing list that a user should be added to when they fill in a newsletter form on our website. I think it will be too much to ask them to find the guid of the marketing list (it took me a bit of work to find it myself)

can anyone share some code to either get the id of a list using the list name as the identifier or let me know if its possible to add a contact to a list using the list name instead of the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [retrieve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieverequest.aspx#Examples) the entity record using `RetrieveRequest`, schema name of that entity (DB table) should be passed as first parameter and primary key (GUID) as second. For Marketing list it is `list` & listid. You should also mention ColumnSet.

```
request.Target = new EntityReference("list", listId);
```

But to achieve what you want, you have to use either [querybyattribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.querybyattribute.aspx#Examples) or queryexpression, then `RetrieveMultiple` will help you to get the Id from name of list.

```
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "new list 1"));
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("list");
query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter);

var result = Context.SystemService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

After that use `AddListMembersListRequest` or [AddMemberListRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.addmemberlistrequest.aspx#Examples) to add members to that list.

```
// Add a list of contacts to the marketing list.
var addMemberListReq = new AddListMembersListRequest
{
    MemberIds = new[] { _contactIdList[0], _contactIdList[2] },
    ListId = listId
};

_serviceProxy.Execute(addMemberListReq);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code gets all lists in Dynamics with a `name` of `"new list 1"`. It then stores the Id of the first list returned if one or more matches were found, or `Guid.Empty` if no matches were found. In your scenario there should be always be one and only one match.

```
var query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "list",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false)
};

query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "new list 1";

var matchingLists = _organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

var defaultListId = matchingLists?.Entities.FirstOrDefault()?.Id ?? Guid.Empty;
```